# Adding two numbers as input in assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, dos

I have to write an assembly program that adds two numbers which were received as input and then prints the sum. Still very new to it and have spend about 15 hours trying to figure this out and its driving me crazy. My problem is I believe somewhere in the multiplication. When i run the program I get weird characters as outputs. I know the program is receiving the numbers properly from inputs and the subtraction works. However when it comes to multiplying everything is messed up. This is also in assembly language 8086. Some help would be appreciated!!

here is my code

```
;-----------------------------------------------------
        .model small
;-----------------------------------------------------
        .stack  64
;-----------------------------------------------------  
        .data
PR      DB      'ENTER: ','$'
Num1    Label   Byte
Max1    DB      3 ; need to hit atmost 3 keys when entering- 2 digits and the enter key
Act1    DB      ?
N1      DB      4 DUP ('$')
Num2    Label   Byte
Max2    DB      3 ; need to hit atmost 3 keys when entering- 2 digits and the enter key
Act2    DB      ?
N2      DB      4 DUP ('$')
Res     DB      3 DUP ('$')
;-----------------------------------------------------
        .code
MAIN    proc    FAR
        mov     AX,@data        ; Initialize segment
        mov     DS,AX           ; registers

        call    CLEAR
        call    SET_CURSOR
        call    REQUEST_INPUT
        call    GET_INPUT1
        call    REQUEST_INPUT
        call    GET_INPUT2
        call    SET_CURSOR
        call        Convert1


        mov     AX,4C00h        ; Exit to DOS
        int     21h
MAIN    endp
;-----------------------------------------------------
CLEAR   proc    NEAR
        mov     AX, 0600H
        mov     BH, 71H
        mov     CX, 0000H
        mov     DX, 184FH
        int     10H
        ret
CLEAR   endp

;-----------------------------------------------------
SET_CURSOR      proc    NEAR
        mov     AH, 02H
        mov     BH, 0           ;sets color of backround 
        mov     DH, 12
        mov     DL, 40
        int     10H
        ret
SET_CURSOR      endp
;-----------------------------------------------------
REQUEST_INPUT   proc    NEAR
        mov     AH, 09H
        lea     DX, PR
        int     21H 
        ret
REQUEST_INPUT   endp

;-----------------------------------------------------
GET_INPUT1       proc    NEAR
        mov     AH, 0AH
        lea     DX,Num1
        int     21H
        mov     BH, 00
        mov     BL, Max1
        mov     N1[BX],'$'
        ret
GET_INPUT1       endp
;-----------------------------------------------------
GET_INPUT2      proc    NEAR
        mov     AH, 0AH
        lea     DX,Num2
        int     21H
        mov     BH, 00
        mov     BL, Max2
        mov     N2[BX],'$'
        ret
GET_INPUT2       endp
;-----------------------------------------------------          
Convert1        proc    NEAR
                  mov     BX, 0
                    mov     AH, 00h
                mov     AL, N1[BX]   ; Get a character
                Mov Ax, 10
                Mul AL
                 mov     BX, 1
                    mov     BH, 00h
                mov     BL, N1[BX]   ; Get a character
                Add AL, BL
                mov     BX, 0
                    mov     CH, 00h
                mov     CL, N2[BX]   ; Get a character
                Mov Ax, 10
                Mul CL
                 mov     BX, 1
                    mov     BH, 00h
                mov     DL, N2[BX]   ; Get a character
                Add CL, DL
                Add AL, CL
                Mov Ax, 10
                Div Al
                Mov Res[0], AL
                Add AH, 48
                call SET_CURSOR2 
                Mov Res[1], AH              
                mov     AH,09h
                lea     DX, Res
                int     21H
                ret

Convert1   endp                                 
;-----------------------------------------------------          






            ;formula ()N1[0]-48)*10 + (N1[1]-48)
            ;same for N2
            ;before printing need to divide result of N1+N2 by 10. the quation is the frist character remainder is the second character- quaotiant will be in AL, Remainder in AH
            ;then need to add 48 before putting them into the array Res
            ;To go back Add Al,48-Mov Res[0], AL


;------------------------------------------------------------
                end     MAIN
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What are you currently getting and what do you expect to be getting? What exactly is your problem? You said you have a problem but not what it is. That will help us help you. Also, which assembly language are you using? To get the most out of your experience at stackoverflow, see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My problem is I believe somewhere in the multiplication. When i run the program I get weird characters as outputs. I know the program is receiving the numbers properly from inputs and the subtraction works. However when it comes to multiplying everything is messed up. This is also in assembly language 8086

Comment: `mov     AL, ...` then `Mov Ax, 10` followed by `Mul AL` is definitively a code smell. `mul al` multiplies `al` by `al`. The result of those instructions is always `ax=100`

Comment: I agree with Margaret Bloom. It looks like you're putting a character into register ax and then immediately overwriting that character with a 10. Register al is just the lower byte of ax.

Comment: So if i need to multiply the value i put into Al by 10, I should move 10 into another register and then multiply?